# Flutter web on mobile loads twice at start

Tags: css, flutter

I released a website and everything was fine. However, I was experiencing a blank screen at the start. To remedy this, I added a loading screen by including the CSS code in `index.html`.

The loading screen works fine, but when I open my website on a mobile browser, the widgets load, disappear, and then load again after the loading screen passes.

How can I resolve this issue?

index.html ;

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <!--
    If you are serving your web app in a path other than the root, change the
    href value below to reflect the base path you are serving from.

    The path provided below has to start and end with a slash "/" in order for
    it to work correctly.

    For more details:
    * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base

    This is a placeholder for base href that will be replaced by the value of
    the `--base-href` argument provided to `flutter build`.
  -->
  <base href="$FLUTTER_BASE_HREF">

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
  <meta name="description" content="Mekanik Perde Çeşitleri Toptan ve Perakende Satış. Kaliteli Hizmet ve Güvenilir Çalışma Anlayışı. Plise perde satış noktası.">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#1D262B">
  <meta name="google-site-verification" content="oziGl7l_uQ__Vc5HZ8IQaKWefNGroqvJOOWzbValmOs" />

  <!-- iOS meta tags & icons -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="nayis_home">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icons/Icon-192.png">

  <!-- Favicon -->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png"/>

  <title>Nayis Tekstil</title>

  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">

  <script>
    // The value below is injected by flutter build, do not touch.
    var serviceWorkerVersion = null;
  </script>
  <!-- This script adds the flutter initialization JS code -->
  <script src="flutter.js" defer></script>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDlnjowKRMtnBonR9C68lYDdwZ3j5jAMZo"></script>

  <style>
    body {background-color: #1D262B;}
  
      .loading {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        margin: 0;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      }
  
      .loader {
      width: 70px;
      height: 70px;
      border: 9px solid transparent;
      border-top-color: #FFFFFF;
      border-right-color: #1D262B;
      border-bottom-color: #FFFFFF;
      border-left-color: #1D262B;
      border-radius: 50%;
      -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
      animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
      }
  
      @-webkit-keyframes spin {
        0% {
          -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        }
        100% {
          -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        }
      }
  
      @keyframes spin {
        0% {
          transform: rotate(0deg);
        }
        100% {
          transform: rotate(360deg);
        }
      }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="loading">
    <div class="loader"></div>
  </div>
  <script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
  <script>
    window.addEventListener('load', function(ev) {
      // Download main.dart.js
      _flutter.loader.loadEntrypoint({
        serviceWorker: {
          serviceWorkerVersion: serviceWorkerVersion,
        }
      }).then(function(engineInitializer) {
        return engineInitializer.initializeEngine();
      }).then(function(appRunner) {
        return appRunner.runApp();
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

(speed up gif, not too clear but i hope it helps for understanding)

[image]